# Mapping a collection to PHP variable for an Oracle DEQUEUE_ARRAY procedure

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I am trying to map the result of a [DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_ARRAY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aq.htm#ARPLS65292) function to a PHP variable.

There's a SQL type defined that would hold the result of the function's payload.

```
CREATE TYPE INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY AS TABLE OF INTERNAL_TYPE;
```

and my script currently looks like the following:

```
<?php

$connection = OracleBase::getOracleConnection();

$query = <<<PLSQL
    DECLARE
      dequeue_options DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
      msg_prop_array  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T;
      msg_id_array    DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T;
      dequeued_cnt    PLS_INTEGER;
      l_array_size    PLS_INTEGER := 1;
      payloads        INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY;

      BEGIN
        payloads := INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY();
        payloads.EXTEND(l_array_size);

        msg_prop_array := DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T();
        msg_prop_array.EXTEND(l_array_size);

        msg_id_array := DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T();
        dequeue_options.wait := 5;

        dequeued_cnt := DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_ARRAY(
            QUEUE_NAME               => 'user.some_queue',
            DEQUEUE_OPTIONS          => dequeue_options,
            ARRAY_SIZE               => l_array_size,
            MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY => msg_prop_array,
            PAYLOAD_ARRAY            => payloads,
            MSGID_ARRAY              => msg_id_array
        );

        :COLLECTION := payloads;

        COMMIT;
    END;
PLSQL;

$stmt = oci_parse($connection, $query);
$collection = oci_new_collection($connection, 'INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY', 'USER');
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':COLLECTION', $collection, 1, SQLT_NTY);
oci_execute($stmt);

$collection->getelem(0); // results in PHP Notice:  OCICollection::getElem(): Unknown or unsupported type of element: 108
```

Unfortunately, my knowledge of Oracle AQ is quite rudimentary and the documentation for PHP is not that detailed. I'd appreciate any insights on how to get this done. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I tried by wrapping it all up into a procedure that returns something as follows:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_DEQUEUE(
        ret out INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY
    ) as
    dequeue_options DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    msg_prop_array  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T;
    msg_id_array    DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T;
    dequeued_cnt    PLS_INTEGER;
    l_array_size    PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    BEGIN
    msg_prop_array := DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T();
    msg_prop_array.EXTEND(l_array_size);
    
    msg_id_array := DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T();
    dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;
    dequeue_options.wait := 10;
    
    dequeued_cnt := DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_ARRAY(
        QUEUE_NAME               => 'user.some_queue',
        DEQUEUE_OPTIONS          => dequeue_options,
        ARRAY_SIZE               => l_array_size,
        MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY => msg_prop_array,
        PAYLOAD_ARRAY            => ret,
        MSGID_ARRAY              => msg_id_array
    );
    COMMIT;
    END;
SQL;
```

I can then do something like this:

```
$sql = "begin SAMPLE_DEQUEUE(:RET); end;";
$stmt = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
$collection = oci_new_collection($connection, 'INTERNAL_TYPE_ARRAY', 'USER');
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':RET', $collection, 1, SQLT_NTY);
$r = oci_execute($stmt);
```

This still results in:

```
PHP Notice:  OCICollection::getElem(): Unknown or unsupported type of element: 108
```

Comment: Fundamentally your question is about PL/SQL and how you map from one type to another, where that second type is something that can be bound by PHP OCI8.  Start by looking at the AQ examples in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) and then the examples in https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_aq.html  Experiment with a non-array dequeue and see how to map the returned value to some scalar (varchar2, number etc) variable values in PL/SQL that you can bind from PHP.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thank you very much for your reply and the fantastic resource. I have no trouble dequeuing a single entity but that's not very performant. I was also able to bind the scalar values into PHP without trouble. The only issue at the moment is to bind the collection returned from DEQUEUE_ARRAY. I edited the question to include what I've tried further by looking at the examples in the book but it is still failing. Appreciate any insights! :)